# Парсинг строки и сравнение значений её элементов

Tags: python, json, строки, парсер

Строка, содержащаяся в файле, выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
[16, 87, 97, 88, 73, 17, 46, 88, 30, 74, 5, 33, 36, 89, 36, 46, 39, 8, 14, 77, 25, 87, 18, 98, 38, 24, 37, 70, 13, 83, 76, 2, 20, 25, 31, 72, 36, 67, 50, 83, 37, 49, 87, 66, 40, 83, 34, 93, 14, 24, 43, 96, 36, 98, 9, 51, 48, 87, 4, 28, 95, 82, 94, 22, 25, 66, 35, 76, 55, 23, 3, 6, 15, 56, 6, 26, 87, 10, 4, 64, 14, 43, 25, 77, 21, 7, 66, 24, 36, 57, 74, 11, 93, 66, 7, 23, 54, 27, 12, 42, 79, 70, 25, 11, 2, 27, 26, 50, 20, 48, 63, 83, 58, 86, 71, 3, 85, 13, 54, 99, 66, 83, 33, 35, 91, 7, 72, 74, 17, 89, 47, 78, 79, 10, 56, 22, 62, 75, 46, 37, 79, 75, 1, 93, 97, 25, 33, 23, 88, 32, 45, 53, 8, 26, 89, 67, 97, 96, 48, 52, 74, 90, 37, 37, 41, 23, 93, 34, 59, 54, 54, 7, 25, 37, 18, 35, 70, 84, 44,  63, 93, 78, 13, 37, 47, 98, 3, 3, 39, 67, 70, 65, 57, 51, 39, 33, 71, 89, 48, 10, 26, 14, 46, 16, 66, 32, 60, 12, 54, 24, 67, 54, 9, 55, 10, 28, 36, 28, 36, 75, 65, 90, 7, 4, 56, 72, 75, 48]
```

Строку в Python (каждое находящееся в ней число - элементы списка) парсить получается, а вот проводить сравнение каждого из элементов списка почему-то не работает, т.к. числовые данные представлены строками, а не int-ами... Фрагмент кода дан ниже:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
from numpy import loadtxt
import pandas as pd

peaks=0
list_of_peaks = []
text_file = open('D:\\MeaningsData.txt', 'r')
list_of_peaks = text_file.read().split(', ')
**int (list_of_peaks)
for i in list_of_peaks:
    if ((list_of_peaks[i]<= list_of_peaks[i-1])):
        peaks=peaks+1**
print(peaks)
```

Компилятор выдает следующую ошибку:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Можете, пожалуйста, предложить лучший способ парсинга строк с числами для того, чтобы значения самих чисел (находящихся в списке или массиве) можно сравнивать?

Comment: json.load(open("file",'rb')) и не надо изобретать парсер...

Comment: тут ещё и пандас подгрузили... так воспользуйтесь им ;) он возможно и пики считать умеет)

Comment: можете выложить ваш файл (или его часть) на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: @MaxU вот - https://dropmefiles.com/zGvqE (файл немного другой)

Comment: @user280617, у вас реально файлы состоят из одной строки или вы их так видоизменили?

Comment: @eri Так все таки лучше json.load или пандас, если мне придется разбить содержимое файла на элементы массива/списка?

Comment: @MaxU из одной строки, но видоизменил в условии самой задачи)

Comment: @user280617 смотря чем вы там занимаетесь.

Answer (score 3):

Читаем файл как JSON (чем он собственно и является):

```
import pandas as pd

peaks = pd.read_json(r"D:\download\MountainsData.txt").iloc[:, 0]
```

Результат (`Pandas Series`):

```
In [9]: peaks
Out[9]:
0      16
1      87
2      97
3      88
4      73
5      17
6      46
       ..
993    90
994     7
995     4
996    56
997    72
998    75
999    48
Length: 1000, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Тут под пиками понимается следующее: точка называется пиком, если две соседние с ней точки НЕ ВЫШЕ или РАВНЫ по высоты с текущей, а стартовая и конечная точки пиками быть не могут

Comment: @user280617, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) ;-) Если хотите задать новый вопрос, например о том как искать пики, то откройте новый SO вопрос...